# SQL Server data migration

Tags: sql-server, database, data-migration

I am trying to figure out the better way to migrate a Database from server A to server B.

MS Data Migration Assistant does a very good job to backup/restore the DB and take care of the move (data, logins, rights, ...). After the move, I need now to check every table of this DB to replace any instance of "\UNC1\XXX" by "\UNC2\YYY", without knowing where I can find this pattern. What would be the best way to achieve that ?

With MySQL I would check the SQL Dump (text) and probably "Replace All" with case insensitive mode.. In my case, either I try to modify data before restore on Server B, or I could try to produce SQL orders to update all tables after restore (but since I want to be exhaustive, I need to check manually all tables which is a bit painful..)

Any ideas or tool to achieve the data transformation "easily" and properly ?

Thanks for help

Comment: in your current database find where all this data lives and put together scripts to update the rows after the database has migrated. I think your question has nothing to do with migration but has everything to do with update of data. Put together a script, test it and have it ready for post migration.

Comment: Tool recommendations are off-topic. But simple web searching will find scripts that search through all columns of all tables in a database - which seems like a good first step. You only need to search varchar or nvarchar columns. And perhaps this problem highlights a flawed design - perhaps fix that (or at least add that task to your to-do list).

Comment: Indeed that I did already (script searching), but hoped for maybe a better way to handle this modification if I ask experienced admins :)

Using cursors and everything for this was a bit too much at first sight, but if there is no other choice...

Comment: Perhaps experiment with the script https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1555/sql-server-find-and-replace-values-in-all-tables-and-all-text-columns/.  If it's a one off, it's not worth worrying too much about.  If this is too slow, then there are more tedious things to try.  If this could be a lookup value, then you would have one place to change it.

Comment: Thanks for pointers, I used the script provided (with ROLLBACK) and it found/updated the values but unfortunately it works only partially as there are some errors
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure UNIT_CONVERT_INS, Line 35 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near '@errno'.